# How to display different levels in a multilevel analysis with different colors

Tags: r, plot, lm

I am a beginner at multilevel analysis and try to understand how I can do graphs with the plot functions from `base-R`. I understand the output of `fit` below but I am struggeling with the visualization. `df` is just some simple test data:

```
t <- seq(0, 10, 1)
df <- data.frame(t = t,
                 y = 1.5+0.5*(-1)^t + (1.5+0.5*(-1)^t) * t,
                 p1 = as.factor(rep(c("p1", "p2"), 10)[1:11]))

fit <- lm(y ~ t * p1, data = df)

# I am looking for an automated version of that:
plot(df$t, df$y)
lines(df$t[df$p1 == "p1"], 
      fit$coefficients[1] + fit$coefficients[2] * df$t[df$p1 == "p1"], col = "blue")
lines(df$t[df$p1 == "p2"], 
      fit$coefficients[1] + fit$coefficients[2] * df$t[df$p1 == "p2"] + 
        + fit$coefficients[3] + fit$coefficients[4] * df$t[df$p1 == "p2"], col = "red")
```

It should know that it has to include `p1` and that there are two lines.
The result should look like this:
[image: Fit with two levels (interactions needs to be included)]

**Edit**: Predict `est <- predict(fit, newx = t)` gives the same result as fit but still I don't know "how to cluster".

**Edit 2 @Keith**: The formula `y ~ t * p1` reads `y = (a + c * p1) + (b + d * p1) * t`. For the "first blue line" `c, d` are both zero.

Comment: Will `t` and `y` always be the same? and will you always have a single factor column?

Comment: A better way of obtaining fitted values would be through `predict()`. Pass on a data.frame as `newdata` for which to predict and be amazed.

Comment: @KeithHughitt No, my real problem will be much more complicated, for a simplified example look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765869/analysis-using-linear-regression-based-on-subgroups). The main purpose of this question is really "how to get the graph with the correct number of lines". Even in this simple case (`p1` only has 2 levels!) I fail;-)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik See my Edit. I know about `predict` (Although I don't understand why it is better than `lm`), but the question here is how to get the "correct number of lines". See also the comment above. It might be a stupid question, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What is 'to cluster'? There is no such argument as `newx`. I don't understand what's wrong with the number of lines here? Number of lines should be as many as there are factor levels in `p1`, am I right?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik You are right. In this case there are 2 lines, although there might be situations with less (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765869/analysis-using-linear-regression-based-on-subgroups)). My question is: How can I plot the 2 fit-lines? I hope the explanation helps.

Comment: My first thought would be to use a for-loop to iterate over `levels(df$p1)` and make a new `line()` for each factor level. If you aren't sure which column is the categorical one, you can also use `sapply(df, is.factor)` to figure that out as well.

Comment: Also, are you missing `coefficients[3]` and `coefficients[4]` in your first call to `line()` above?

Comment: @KeithHughitt I don't think I have to include them: My (poor) understanding is that the coefs are ordered according to the formula. Thus, the "first line" corresponds to "not include coefs 3 and 4". See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it. I'm including a `ggplot2` version of plot as well because I find it better fitted for the way I think about plots.
This version will account for the number of levels in `p1`. If you want to compensate for the number of model parameters, you will just have to adjust the way you construct `xy` to include all the relevant variables. I should point out that if you omit the `newdata` argument, fitting will be done on the dataset provided to `lm`.

```
t <- seq(0, 10, 1)
df <- data.frame(t = t,
                 y = 1.5+0.5*(-1)^t + (1.5+0.5*(-1)^t) * t,
                 p1 = as.factor(rep(c("p1", "p2"), 10)[1:11]))

fit <- lm(y ~ t * p1, data = df)

xy <- data.frame(t = t, p1 = rep(levels(df$p1), each = length(t)))
xy$fitted <- predict(fit, newdata = xy)

library(RColorBrewer) # for colors, you can define your own
cols <- brewer.pal(n = length(levels(df$p1)), name = "Set1") # feel free to ignore the warning

plot(x = df$t, y = df$y)
for (i in 1:length(levels(xy$p1))) {
  tmp <- xy[xy$p1 == levels(xy$p1)[i], ]
  lines(x = tmp$t, y = tmp$fitted, col = cols[i])
}
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(xy, aes(x = t, y = fitted, color = p1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = t, y = y)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]